# How to setup virtual remote (vnc) desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to create a virtual desktop on a MacBook Pro and access it from a windows machine. The windows machine has three displays and I want see the virtual desktop on all three displays.

For reference, what I'm looking for is something like the [vncserver](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vncserver) package for linux, or windows RDP with the options "use all my monitors for the remote session".

Currently I'm using Remote Management to access my mac desktop. I followed [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118819/create-virtual-display-for-use-with-remote-desktop) and now I can access the MacBook without others seeing what I am doing. Progress!

But the System Preferences > Displays panel only has a single choice in the list for Resolution: Scaled, which is 1496 x 967. That is lower-res than my windows displays.

Is it possible to create and access an arbitrary-sized virtual desktop on the MacBook?

Comment: What kind of 'virtual desktop'? [this isn't a term used on Mac & I'm struggling to translate to one that is]. Are you trying to remote mount three displays from a Mac that only has one physical display? This is not possible. You'd need dummy HDMI plugs to fake two additional displays. You can create arbitrarily-sized remote display by simply dragging the corner of the window to a different size [when remoting Mac to Mac, never tried it from Windows]

Comment: That's the idea of "virtual", and the original idea of the V in a VNC service. There is no need for physical hardware. For example, the vncserver package for linux (linked in the question) allows for creating a virtual display of arbitrary size, for example, 3200 x 900. In the case of windows RDP, the virtual desktop can be made to fit the displays on the local client. The only instructions I found to connect a windows client to mac host uses a VNC client. But it looks like maybe mac only supports physical displays?

Comment: You seem to be conflating two pieces of information - being able to make the single remote screen area any size you like is not the same as asking it for displays it does not possess.

Comment: The software feature I'm asking for is available on linux and windows, by different names on each platform. I have described the feature using the names used by those platforms. Perhaps it simply is not available on macos. Or maybe it goes by a different name that I do not yet know.